# Passing a file descriptor through libvirt to qemu (C api)

Tags: c, virtualization, qemu, libvirt

As the title says I'm looking for a way to pass a C-style file descriptor (int, my application uses socketpair, and I need to pass one of the file descriptors) through the libvirt API onto the launched QEMU process.

I found the following so far:

- virDomainOpenGraphics
- virDomainOpenGraphicsFD

sadly these don't seem to help me as they are only for graphics,

- virDomainCreateWithFiles
- virDomainCreateXMLWithFiles

sadly these also don't help because according to the documentation they only work with container based virtualization technology.

Any way I can pass a file descriptor to qemu for my own purposes using the libvirt API would be great. Barring a way to do this I might have to write a completely custom backend for QEMU, however my application is already invested in using libvirt and the change would be significant.

EDIT: The file descriptor would be a socket, it isn't used directly by QEMU, I have a LD_PRELOAD-ed library that would use this socket instead to do some in-place hacks when qemu tries to read/write to a particular disk. The "hacks" vary on a per-machine basis as well as per-run basis, writing this information to disk for each VM would overburden the storage system and cause a very significant slowdown which I can't afford.

Comment: A "file descriptor" in C is an `int` that identifies a file opened with `open()`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, edited the question to clarify, hope it's more understandable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except in the specialized case of virDomainOpenGraphics, libvirt wouldn't generally expect an application to need to pass in pre-opened file descriptors. Instead apps tell libvirt what resources QEMU needs to access, and if appropriate libvirt will open the resource & pass its file descriptor to QEMU without the application needing to care about this low level detail.

The question doesn't say why you need to pass an FD - what kind of FD is & what will it be used for by QEMU. So its hard to give any guidance about the next step to take.

Comment: edited the question so others can also see the details, thanks for the feedback

Comment: What is described with an LD_PRELOAD hack is really something that is not going to be considered supported from a libvirt POV. While it is possible to set the env var to load the preloaded library via libvirt XML, we don't have any mechanism for passing in an FD for this to use. We're not likely to add new APIs to cope with this either, given its hacky nature. Probably you would need to make your LD_PRELOAD directly open the socket(s) it needs

Comment: Thanks @DanielB, I still need a mechanism to tell the library some parameters and keep them secret from the other processes, I suppose you're right about it never being supported for this purpose but I could imagine cases where people want to manage some device directly through a file descriptor from their application (such as for example a virtual serial port endpoint). Seeing as libvirt is a library and passing file descriptors is already implemented in it (for graphics purposes) I don't see why something more generic would not be allowed.

Comment: accepted the answer, however I find the situation sad :(